# Tag suggestion of 'Exopolitics'

Tags: discussion, tags

> Exopolitics is a new scientific discipline that focuses on the
>   political aspects of interactions with extraterrestrial life. It
>   studies the key individuals, institutions and political processes that
>   are associated with extraterrestrial life in general, as well as, more
>   specifically, those associated with the extraterrestrial presence here
>   on Earth. It therefore belongs to the political sciences.

Source: http://www.exopaedia.org/Exopolitics

> Exopolitics is defined as an interdisciplinary scientific field, with
>   its roots in the political sciences, that focuses on research,
>   education and public policy with regard to the actors, institutions
>   and processes, associated with extraterrestrial life, as well as the
>   wide range of implications this entails through public advocacy and
>   newly emerging paradigms.

Source:
http://www.exopoliticsinstitute.org/

---

[image: Exopolitics fields of research]

---

Suggested questions to tag:

- [Are there public laws dealing with extraterrestrial contact?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/are-there-public-laws-dealing-with-extraterrestrial-contact)
- [Are alien visitors in Area 51?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/757/are-alien-visitors-in-area-51)
- [Are there public laws dealing with extraterrestrial contact?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/are-there-public-laws-dealing-with-extraterrestrial-contact)
- [Have there been any credible reports of unidentified flying objects?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/765/have-there-been-any-credible-reports-of-unidentified-flying-objects)
- [Did the USSR send a flying disk with mutant childlike aviators to Roswell in 1947?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/did-the-ussr-send-a-flying-disk-with-mutant-childlike-aviators-to-roswell-in-194)
- [What is the current state of the evidence of the existence of the so-called Nazi UFO's?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-evidence-of-the-existence-of-the-so-called-nazi)

Comment: What existing questions would this apply to?

Comment: Updated list of questions.

Comment: It's because exopolitics is more about politics, government, and law. It's a new scientific discipline that focuses on the political aspects of interactions with extraterrestrial life.

Comment: These are just suggested questions, I didn't get too deeply into every questions. Buying star can be ignored. Area 51 is owned by US government, so it could have political aspects involved.

Comment: Added image from Exopaedia to define its roots and fields of research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a good tag to add at this time. It isn't a well-established  term that will be useful for site visitors or users.

- It doesn't have a Wikipedia article (which *suggests* non-notability of the term)
- Everything I can find online about the term circles back to the work of [Alfred Webre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Webre#Exopolitics), whose theories that are labelled exopolitics posit that we are living on a quarantined planet and are being given an opportunity to join the rest of the spiritually evolved universe society. His university has [courses like](http://exouniversity.org/courses/) "Jump Room 101: US chrononaut Andrew D. Basiago discusses the CIA’s Mars visitation program of the 1980’s".
- Other websites using the term:

  - http://www.exopoliticscanada.ca/: "We exist for one reason, and that is to help end the truth embargo concerning the reality of UFO's."
  - http://exopolitics.blogspot.ca/: "Exopolitics is based upon the understanding that earth is being visited by many advanced extraterrestrial races with diverse ethics, motives and agendas."
  - http://exopolitics.blogs.com/: Articles on the "UFO conspiracys", "18 beings on Mars", "Saturn/Moon matrix as platform for mind control on Earth", among others.. None of the exopolitics "news" on that site is science-based.
  - http://exopolitics.org/: Contains the definition that you provided, but it doesn't say much. Its [first listed research article is titled "The Need for Exopolitics: Implications of Extraterrestrial Conspiracy Theories for Policy Makers & Global Peace"](http://exopolitics.org/Study-Paper1.htm) and advocates for "official government disclosure of an ET presence". Their second research paper argues that "competing clandestine government organizations are struggling through proxy means to take control of ancient extraterrestrial (ET) technology that exists in Iraq".

Even if we *were* to add a tag, I would not be in support of the definition you provide.

- The definition you provide seems to be inaccurate, and not descriptive of what the word "exopolitics" is actually used for (at least on sites that I found on the first page of Google). Exopolitics is largely associated with *non-scientific* beliefs and pseudoscience.
- The definition you provide doesn't say what exopolitics *is*.

  - It says what it is rooted in (who cares).
  - It says exopolitics is an interdisciplinary scientific field (it isn't).
  - It says exopolitics "focuses on research, education and public policy" (that sounds like something an *organization* would do, not a field of research).
  - "with regard to the actors, institutions and processes, associated with extraterrestrial life" - Associated by whom? It seems this can encompass *anybody* that exopoliticists think is associated with extraterrestrial life, so this part of the definition isn't actually limiting.
  - as well as the wide range of implications this entails through public advocacy and newly emerging paradigms (what does this even mean?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You may add as well The [Exopolitics Institute](http://www.exopoliticsinstitute.org) site who is dedicated to the study, promotion and support of exopolitics. They've also announced Declaration for a [Hawaii Star Visitor Sanctuary](http://www.hawaiistarvisitorsanctuary.org/).